# is "zero" a reserved tag number in cocoa?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, tags, uibutton

I want to know if zero is a reserved tag number in cocoa.

I ask because I was building UIButtons in a for loop from 0 - n and assinging the loop index as each created buttons tag.

Then when I tried to reference using viewWithTag and tried to change a property I get a sigbart error for the button with tag zero. All of the other buttons work fine.

To get my code to work I've had to create the buttons using for 1 - n+1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`tag` is an integer instance variable in UIView subclasses and as any other integer ivar it is initialized with 0 by default.

So in your case any subview tag that was not set explicitly to some value will be equal to 0 and if there are several such subviews `viewWithTag:` method may return any of them - probably it just returns not an UIButton instance and you access some button-specific properties in your code so getting exception (unrecognized selector sent?) in run-time.

Comment: That explain my problem too. tagging uibutton as zero and all buttons are working with unexpected behavior :(

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag), the default value for a tag is zero. (i.e.: UIViews, etc. with no specific tag value set will be zero.) As such, it's likely that the SIGBART is being caused by the fact that you're attempting to reference multiple (or simply an invalid) control when you call viewWithTag with a zero value.

In order words, you should really start custom tag numbering at 1.

Comment: Can you reference the documentation? Thanks.

Comment: @KarenAnne I've updated my answer with a link to the [UIView class tag property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/tag). Hope this helps.